# if $\sinh(x)=\frac{x}{a}$ why isn't $\tanh(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> if $\sinh(x)=\frac{3}{5}$ why isn't $\tanh(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$?

According to the answer key it is actually $\tanh(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}$

But I don't understand that because we see that when I draw out a triangle it shows otherwise

Comment: Please define $a$

Comment: Tell us what you think $\cosh x$ is

Comment: Start with $\cosh^2 x$

Comment: Because $\sinh$ and $\tanh$ are not $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use
$\tanh(x)
= \dfrac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)}
= \dfrac{\sinh(x)}{\sqrt{\sinh^2(x)+1}}
$
since
$\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)
= 1
$.

I also don't see where
"$a$" came from.

Answer (score 1):

$\sinh(x)^2+1=\cosh(x)^2$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle \cosh(x)=\frac{\sqrt{34}}{5}$.

And then $\displaystyle \tanh(x)=\boxed{\frac{3}{\sqrt{34}}}$.

And guys, he meant $\displaystyle \frac{x}{a}$ probably, instead of $\displaystyle \frac{3}{5}$.

But then he should've used $t$ as an input or something.

Because if $\sinh(t)=x$, then $\displaystyle \cosh(t)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}{a}$.

Then $\tanh(t)=\displaystyle \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$, and it all makes sense.